# Many to one mappings in Java

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, mapping, key-value

I am trying to build a many to one key value pair in java. Till now all I have manged is this

```
  public class KeyStore {
    int i=1;
    Map<Integer,String> map1=new HashMap<Integer,String>();
    Map<String,List<Integer>> map2=new HashMap<String,List<Integer>>();

    public synchronized int put(String blobString) {
    if(map1.containsValue(blobString)){
    int r=blobString.hashCode()+i*blobString.hashCode();
    i++;
    map1.put(r, blobString);
    List<Integer> j=map2.get(blobString);
    List<Integer> k=j;
    map2.remove(blobString);
    k.add(r);
    map2.put(blobString, k);
    return r;

}
else{
    map1.put(blobString.hashCode(),blobString);
    List<Integer> x=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    x.add(blobString.hashCode());
    map2.put(blobString,x);
    return blobString.hashCode();
}
}

     public synchronized String get(int objectId) {
         return map1.get(objectId);
  }
```

What this does is if i `put`

```
  ks.put("abc") 

  ks.put("abc")
```

Here ks is an instant of the class containing the above methods.

it results in

```
{1916062554=abc, 958031277=abc}
```

But what I want is

```
191602554,958031277=abc
```

and if i use `get()` on either of these keys it should output the value abc. Also `delete()` should delete the most recent key and not harm the other keys.

I thought of using

```
Map<ArrayList<Integer>,String> keystore=new HashMap<ArrayListInteger>,String>();
```

but I dont know how to implement the put method i.e how to insert a key in a map of lists. Need help with this.

### **EDIT 1**

I am able to make the get and put methods work. Struggling with the delete method. Wrote it some what like this

```
Map<Integer,String> map1=new HashMap<Integer,String>();
Map<String,List<Integer>> map2=new HashMap<String,List<Integer>>();

public synchronized void delete(int objectId) {
  map1.remove(objectId);
  Iterator<Entry<String, List<Integer>>> it = map2.entrySet().iterator();
 loop1: while (it.hasNext()) {
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Integer> z=(List<Integer>) pairs.getValue();
         if(z.contains(objectId)){
             //System.out.println(z.size());
             String key=(String) pairs.getKey();
             System.out.println(z+" "+key);
            if(z.size()==1){
                map2.remove(key);
                break loop1;
            }
            else{
                z.remove(objectId);
                map2.remove(key);
                map2.put(key, z);
                break loop1;
            }
        }
  }
  }
```

Basically map1 contains the mappings

```
123=>abc,456=>abc
```

and map2 contains

```
abc=>[123,456]
```

I am getting an arrayindexoutofbound exception. What I am trying in the delete method is to iterate across each blob String and then check in the list of values associated with the blobstring whetehr the required objectID is present. if it is then I remove that object id from the list and append the new mapping. Any help?

**EDIT 2**

The updated and working get and put methods are given above.

Comment: Is it an option to only store one key-value pair and do some modulo (or other) conversion before doing a `get()`? It works well if your key generation follows specific rules.

Comment: "do some modulo (or other) conversion" where exactly will you apply the conversion?

Comment: You have some function `getValue(key)` which in turn generates the appropriate key for the actual `get`, for example.

Comment: I added the get method in the question just now

Comment: A few odd things here. You say `keystore.put("abc")` but `keystore` is a HashMap, and `HashMap.put()` has two arguments.

Comment: I will modify the keystore.put("abc") part its actually trying to denote an instance of the class containg the above methods and I am not using the same hashcode I am using blobString.hashCode()+i*blobString.hashCode(); where i is constantly incrementing

Comment: I took the liberty of putting a class declaration around your code. If it's wrong please edit it.

Comment: no thats absolutely fine

Comment: You're inserting something generated (the Integer part) in you HashMap so obviously you will want to search on the String part in your HashMap (the one you know). In my opinion, it seems consistent to use the String part as the key and then to have something like Map<String, ArrayList<Integer>>. Then search for your String key and if it exists add the Integer value in your list : if(keystore.containsKey("abc")) { keystore.get("abc").add(generatedId)} else{keystore.put("abc", new ArrayList<Integer>(){{add(generatedId);}});

Answer (score 1):

The [Map JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) says:

> A map cannot contain duplicate keys; each key can map to at most one value.

But you can get around this by making the value a *list* of strings:

```
   import  java.util.ArrayList;
   import  java.util.HashMap;
   import  java.util.Iterator;
   import  java.util.List;
   import  java.util.Map;
   import  java.util.Set;

/**
   <P>{@code java MultiValueHashMap}</P>
 **/
public class MultiValueHashMap  {
   public static final void main(String[] ignored)  {
      Map<Integer,List<String>> mapOfIntStrs = new HashMap<Integer,List<String>>();

      //Add elements
         addStringToMap(mapOfIntStrs, 1, "one");
         addStringToMap(mapOfIntStrs, 1, "two");
         addStringToMap(mapOfIntStrs, 1, "three");
         addStringToMap(mapOfIntStrs, 2, "four");
         addStringToMap(mapOfIntStrs, 2, "five");

      //Output 
         Set<Integer> keyNumSet = mapOfIntStrs.keySet();
         Iterator<Integer> keyNumItr = keyNumSet.iterator();
         while(keyNumItr.hasNext())  {
            Integer keyNum = keyNumItr.next();
            List<String> strList = mapOfIntStrs.get(keyNum);
            System.out.println(keyNum);
            for(String s : strList)  {
               System.out.println("  " + s);
            }
         }
   }
   private static final void addStringToMap(Map<Integer,List<String>> mapTo_addTo, int keyNum, String value)  {
      if(mapTo_addTo.containsKey(keyNum))  {
         mapTo_addTo.get(keyNum).add(value);
      }  else  {
         List<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();
         strList.add(value);
         mapTo_addTo.put(keyNum, strList);
      }
   }

}
```

Output:

```
[C:\java_code\]java MultiValueHashMap
1
  one
  two
  three
2
  four
  five
```

---

Regarding multiple keys per value, you could certainly do this, although I'm not sure it's recommended. According to the [`HashMap` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html):

> The HashMap class is roughly equivalent to Hashtable, except that it is unsynchronized and permits nulls.

And the [`Hashtable` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html):

> To successfully store and retrieve objects from a hashtable, the objects used as keys must implement the hashCode method and the equals method.

So while this would work with `ArrayList<Integer>` keys, for anything with customized keys, containing non-standard classes, unless you are correctly implementing `hashCode()` for those objects, the `HashMap` may not function properly.

Comment: Could you change this implementation to multiple key one value rather than one key multiple values as the get wont work here?

Comment: Updated my answer for your question.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you need a couple of data structures as fields in your class:

- stringMap: `Map<Integer,String>`

  - `{1916062554=abc, 958031277=abc}`, etc.
  - because for `get` you want to look up items by key
- keys: `Map<String,List<Integer>>`

  - `{ "abc" = {1916062554, 958031277}`
  - because for `delete` you want to know the keys for a given item, in order.

To add to the Map:

```
 public void put(String item) {
     List<Integer> list = getOrCreateList(item,keys);
     int key = calculateKey(item,list);
     list.add(key);
     stringMap.put(key,item);
 }

 private static List<Integer> getOrCreateList(String item, Map<String,List<Integer>> map) {
     List<Integer> list = map.get(item);
     if(list == null) {
         list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
         map.put(item,list);
     }
     return list;
 }
```

To get from the map is easy:

```
 public String get(int key) {
     return stringMap.get(key);
 }
```

To delete from the map -- if I understand your requirements correctly -- you need to find the most recent key in the list corresponding to the key provided...

```
 public void delete(int key) {
     String item = stringMap.get(key);
     if(item == null) {
        // ... deal with
     }
     List<Integer> keys = keys.get(item);

     // lazily using methods which don't exist in the Java API
     // but which illustrate the point.
     keys.removeLast();
     if(keys.isEmpty()) {
         stringMap.remove(key);
         list.remove(item);
     }
 }
```

Comment: list = new ArrayList<String,List<Integer>>(); bug?

Comment: @Sarkar why do you think that?

Comment: Oh got it. Actually the bug was on the previous line - variable declared as a Map when it should have been a list.